# Does OP mean the questioner?

Tags: discussion

I have not been sure of the right way to refer to the person who wrote a question. I often encounter `OP`, which seems like that, but I am not sure. Does OP mean the questioner? If so, what is it abbreviated for? If not, what is the good way to refer to the person who is asking?

Comment: FYI : [Stack Overflow Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe it stands for Original Poster (or occasionally Original Post, depending on context), and is generally used to refer to the creator of the thread on a forum. On SE it's generally used to mean the questioner.